# Complete Server Lockdown Command Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make a command which locks the whole server in discord.py but when I use the command, it just locks the channel which I used it in. Please help me if you can, Here is my current code.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lockdown(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role,send_messages=False)
    embedVar3 = discord.Embed(
      title="Locked",
      description=(f'***Server has been locked.***'),
    colour=(0x0000ff))
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar3)
```

Comment: The current command just locks the channel I use the command in. Please tell me if there is a way to lock the whole server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to loop through each channel in the guild can lock each channel individually. Looking at the documentation, there doesn't seem to be a method for locking down the entire server.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lockdown(ctx):
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
        ...
```

[Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)

Comment: This "Documentation" is really confusing for me, Can you please give me a code example of "loop through each channel" ?

Comment: @GameMaker The code example is included in my answer.

Comment: If I use that exact same code, will it work for me?

Comment: @GameMaker In theory, yes. The `for` loop iterates through all the channels in the guild and locks each channel individually. Thus, technically speaking, the entire guild will be locked.

Comment: It worked, but when using the "unlockall" command, it makes it such that members can chat in channels which they are not supposed it. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @GameMaker That is outside the scope of this question and would likely warrant a separate question.